Why does $\rm{H_2 O}$ have 12 degrees of freedom?
I know there will be 3 translational D.O.F. and 3 rotational D.O.F., and it can have 4 vibrational D.O.F. (one potential and one kinetic) for each O-H Bond. But from where does 2 more D.O.F. come from? I am also not sure about the 4 vibrational D.O.F that I talked about. Is it really 4 or not? Well, it should be but when I searched on internet regarding this it showed that 6 Vibrational D.O.F. in water vapor are asymmetric, symmetric, wagging, twisting, scissoring and rocking. I don't know the meaning of each term so please also explain that.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/322057/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/193249/2451 and links therein.

Are you treating the bond angle as fixed ? Or do you need to include DOFs where the bond angle flexes ?

Does this answer your question? Why does $H_2$ have $C_V$=$7/2 R$ at high temperatures, while the total number of degrees of freedom is 6?

@gandalf61 -I am considering all situations that can happen.

@ john Rennie - can you share some resources regarding this topic as I was not able to completely understand it

@Ujjwal If you didn't include flexing of the bond angle in your original count then I think that gives you the extra 2 DOFs. In the terminology you have added to the question, I think these DOFs would be "scissoring" and "twisting".

I don't think this is an exact duplicate of the linked question. This question is about water but the linked question is about hydrogen.

yeah but I got the point that was I was missing from that answer
